# Pinterest IOS SDK getBoardPins response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)"

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, pinterest

I'm getting a bad request return on

```
 PDKClient.sharedInstance().getBoardPins(boardID, fields: ["image", "description"], withSuccess: { (responseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in

            print(responseObject.pins().first!.descriptionText)

            })  { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
                print("error NSError: \(err)")
        }
```

passing boardID from:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? PinCollectionViewController {
           dvc.boardID = selectedBoard.identifier
    }
```

and I can't figure out why? I know that my board ID is correct and tried hard coding it.  I've already been authenticated...

From the SDK:

```
/**
 *  Get a list of pins for the given board. The response can be used to get
 *  the bext page of pins.
 *
 *  @param boardId      ID of the board
 *  @param fields       The pin fields that will be returned by the api
 *  @param successBlock Called when the API call succeeds
 *  @param failureBlock Called when the API call fails
 */
- (void)getBoardPins:(NSString *)boardId
              fields:(NSSet *)fields
         withSuccess:(PDKClientSuccess)successBlock
          andFailure:(PDKClientFailure)failureBlock;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the fields to:

```
PDKClient.sharedInstance().getBoardPins(boardID, fields: ["id", "image", "note"], withSuccess: { (responseObject :PDKResponseObject!) -> Void in

        print(responseObject.pins().first!.descriptionText)

        })  { (err :NSError!) -> Void in
            print("error NSError: \(err)")
    }
```

And was able to successfully receive a response